# How to setup Spek Framework

Tags: gradle, junit5, spek

I've checked the docs:
https://spekframework.org/migration/#maven-coordinates

I wanted to try out version 2.x.x, so I added in `build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation ("org.spekframework.spek2:spek-dsl-jvm:2.0.0")
testRuntimeOnly ('org.spekframework.spek2:spek-runner-junit5')
```

But Gradle is unable to find that 2.x.x library in Maven Central:
https://search.maven.org/search?q=spek-dsl-jvm

What should I do? Is there a special repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following maven repo to your build file:

```
repositories {    
  jcenter()
}
```

Then for the dependencies:

```
testCompile group: 'org.spekframework.spek2', name: 'spek-dsl-jvm', version: '2.0.0-rc.1'
testCompile group: 'org.spekframework.spek2', name: 'spek-runner-junit5', version: '2.0.0-rc.1'
```

You could also checkout https://github.com/spekframework/spek-multiplatform-example for more info.

Answer (score 1):

try to configure your repositories with:
`maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot'}`

Your dependency should be as follows:

`dependency "org.spekframework.spek2:spek-dsl-jvm:$spekVersion"`

where `spekVersion = "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`